# How do I permanently disable Notification Center in Big Sur?

Tags: notifications, big-sur

How do I permanently disable Notification Center in Big Sur (M1), but keep the "Badge App Icon"? I don't need it at all including so called widgets etc.

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist does not work anymore!
```

Also, reportedly there was an Notification App, but I cannot find it in Big Sur.

Comment: FWIW, I found a [solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/421674/disabling-notification-center-in-macos-big-sur-11-4) that seems to work in Big Sur 11.4, but you have to keep System Integrity Protection turned off.